# Solve $ \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}\right) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have to solve

> $$ \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}\right) $$

How many times do I have to apply L'Hopital in this?

Comment: I think once, since the sine in the numerator goes to cosine, and $\cos(0)=1$.

Comment: zero. In a neighbourhood of the origin $\sqrt{1-\cos x} = \sqrt{2}\,\text{sign}(x)\sin\frac{x}{2}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that, near $0$, $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}$ has the same sign as $x$. Therefore, either your limit does not exist or it is equal to $0$. On the other hand,\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}\right)^2&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{1-\cos x}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}1+\cos x\\&=2.\end{align}Therefore$$\lim_{x\to0^\pm}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}=\pm\sqrt2$$and your limit does not exist.

Notice that I applied L'Hopital's rule $0$ times in order to prove this.

Comment: I think we need to say original function is odd so that's why it doesn't exist...

Comment: The OP is asking about LHR here.

Comment: I don't get why it doesn't exist, we are gettings $ \sqrt{2} $

Comment: @samjoe I believe that the fact that the sign of $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}$ is equal to the sign of $x$ (which I mentioned) is enough.

Comment: @MarkViola You are right. I have added a sentence to my answer because of that.

Comment: @Husun No, we are not. We are obtaining $\sqrt2$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from the right and $-\sqrt2$ when $x$ approaches it from the left.

Comment: @jose yeah I know, still doesn't make much difference :)

Comment: Why does it say that "near $0$, $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}\gt0$"? is the "$\gt0$" vestigial?

Comment: It's so nice to hear that we have to apply that infamous L'Hospital's Rule only $0$ times. +1

Comment: @robjohn Yes, it was vestigial. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

write $$\frac{\sin(x)\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}}{\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}}$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

> L'Hospital's Rule doesn't work here as it leads to an endless loop.  See the development following the hint.

---

**HINT:**

Since applying L'Hospital's Rule fails, I wanted to provide a hint toward analyzing the limit of interest.

Note that $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(x/2)$.

Judiciously apply the limit, $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$.

You will find that the limit fails to exist since the right-side and left-side limits are not equal.

---

To see the futility of L'Hospital's Rule, we apply LHR once to find

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{\frac12 (1-\cos(x))^{-1/2}\,\sin(x)}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\cos(x)\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}{\sin(x)}
\end{align}$$

A second application reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\cos(x)\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}{\sin(x)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{-2\sin(x)\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}+2\cos(x)\frac12(1-\cos(x))^{-1/2}\,\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}-2\tan(x)\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

If the proposed limit exists, then since $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-2\tan(x)\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}\right)=0$, we find after two applications of LHR that we are back to where we started.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}=\frac{\sin(x)}{|\sin(x)|}\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}=\sqrt2
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}=-\sqrt2
$$
Therefore, since the limits from different directions are different, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim _{x\to 0^{\pm}}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}\right)$$
$$= \lim _{x\to 0^{\pm}}\left(\frac{2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{2}|\sin \frac{x}{2}|}\right)$$
$$=\pm\sqrt{2}$$

$(\because \sin x=2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{x}{2}, 1-\cos x=2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2})$

please note that Here I applied LHR zero times.

Comment: The OP is asking about LHR here.

Comment: @MarkViola LHR is not working here, as you noted above.

Comment: I know.  I believe that the OP is questioning how to proceed using LHR.  You've not addressed that quest at all here.  You merely show another way forward.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{1-\cos{x}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin{x}}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|}=\sqrt2\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}{\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}}}=\sqrt2;$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{1-\cos{x}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\sin{x}}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|}=-\sqrt2\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}{\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}}}=-\sqrt2.$$

Answer (score 0):

This limit does not exist so you do not have to use L'Hospital's rule at all. Use half angle formulas for sin(x) and 1-cos(x). Simplify and you will get$\sqrt{2}$ 
 for the right limit and - $\sqrt{2}$ for the left limit. A graph or a table of values will be helpful to see the jump from one side of zero to the other side.